# Mathematically creating a scale model of a tank

Tags: geometry

I am having a difficult time solving the following question:

The theme park company is building a scale model of the killer whale stadium main show tank for an investor's presentation. Each dimension will be made 6 times smaller to accommodate the mock-up in the presentation room. How many times smaller than the actual volume is the volume of the mock-up?

[image]

To show that I have put effort into my assignment I will show you how I got the volume. Please note that it is given that the main show tank has a radius of 70 feet, and it is also given that it is a quarter of sphere despite the visual. Density Calculations is irrelavent, so please ignore that.

[image]

As you can see, the volume is 359,006.6... cubic feet.

This leads me to the question of how should I make each dimension 6 times smaller, and how would I find how many times smaller is the scale model's volume that the actual volume?

Comment: If you divide the actual radius by $6$, the volume gets scaled by $(1/6)^3$. So you may simply multiply the actual volume by $(1/6)^3$ to get the volume of scale model.

Comment: @GaneshTadi To find how many times the scale model's volume is smaller than the actual volume I would divide the original volume by the scale model's volume giving me a quotient of 216. Is this correct? If so, I recommend you make your comment into an answer; it helped me greatly.

Comment: Exactly ! In general :  if all the dimensions scale by a factor of $k$, then the volume scales by a factor of $k^3$

Comment: @GaneshTadi Thanks for the great information!